# Files external to the project cause build to fail due to view id not found

Tags: android, xml, gradle, layout

[image]

I don't know what's causing this. The only thing I added was recyclerview and cardview to the project. Then, it stopped working. I double checked that my `@id`s are all `@+id`s but still nothing changed.

I narrowed down the error: it only stops happening when I change the Id of this textview from whatever I specify to `title`
[image]

Here is the view :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:elevation="3dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="Event Title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eventCardImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventCardDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/eventCardImage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:text="Big Long Event Description"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is really annoying. I guess it's a generative thing that happens on the build proccess and has a hardcoded title inside, or I am doing something wrong.

Edit: Found error
Edit: Screenshot
Edit: Post XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rebuilt the project hope it will work fine if it doesn't try to restart the android studio.
If you are using cardview or recycle-view make sure you have added the required gradle dependencies.
Remove the + sign from id when using as reference.
replace android:layout_below="@+id/title" With android:layout_below="@id/title"

Comment: Restarted android studio, dependencies are already there (if not, it would insta fail), no fix

Comment: goto File-> Invalidate cache/ Restart

Comment: Please post the xml view too.

Comment: replace this             android:layout_below="@+id/eventCardImage"
With             android:layout_below="@id/eventCardImage"

Comment: also             android:layout_below="@+id/title"
With             android:layout_below="@id/title"

Comment: Remove the plus from id when using as reference.